# What songs are good for an young alto? (10-13)

Tags: voice

I am a young teen who is trying to  find some songs for me, because everything comes out airy or soft. Is this normal for a person my age? Please help!

Comment: Welcome! We need a *lot* more information. Pop, classical, jazz, what? Male or female? Gentle or belting? Help us to help you. Although asking for particular songs, or a list of songs isn't really what the site's about.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to this question is to adjust the range of any song you may want to sing so that your voice can sing it without straining itself. You should do this with each song you choose for yourself because they won't all result in the same key. If you play an instrument, you can learn to do this "finding of the right key" by yourself. If you don't play an instrument,( I'm thinking piano or guitar ) you may need to find some one to help you through the process. I personally cannot justify limiting myself to songs that others have worked up, and they just happen to be in a key that I can sing. Almost every song can be adjusted into a key that will fit your vocal range.
You start the process in the key the sheet music indicates, then decide for yourself if it needs to move up higher or lower, then move in half-steps or whole steps up or down the alphabet until you find a key that is comfortable for your vocal range. Once you get the hang of it, it becomes pretty easy.

Comment: This process is called "Transposing", adjusting a song from one key to another.

Answer (score 0):

Most pop songs sung by girls are in a very low range - it would be hard to give an answer if you were asking for songs for soprano (like maybe W. Houston or M. Carey with a broad range). So you don't have to ask and look for a special song. Just take what you like and if you catch just the 2-3 wrong ones let them drop.

P.S:And please mind Tim's comment.

Comment: And don't feel obliged to sing in the key the track was sung in. Find your own.